# element use in D3.js

Tags: d3.js

It seems the code is good, but the seamless execution is not. The  elements are out of the  element. What do I do wrong?

```
var body = d3.select("body");

var svg = body.append("svg")
            .attr("width", 500)
            .attr("height", 800);

svg.append("defs")
            .append("rect")
            .attr("id", "square")
            .attr("width", 50)
            .attr("height", 50);

var row = d3.range(10, 361, 50);
console.log(row);

svg.append("g")
            .attr("id", "row1")
            .data(row)
            .enter()
                .append("use")
                .attr("href","#square")
                .attr("y", 10)
                .attr("x", function(d){return d})
                .attr("stroke-width", 2)
                .attr("stroke", "yellow")
                .attr("fill", "red");
```

look at the exit:

[Using the Chromium browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGe5k.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed `.selectAll("use")` before binding data.

```js
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 500)
  .attr("height", 800);

svg.append("defs")
  .append("rect")
  .attr("id", "square")
  .attr("width", 50)
  .attr("height", 50);

var row = d3.range(10, 361, 50);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("id", "row1")
  .selectAll("use")
  .data(row)
  .enter()
  .append("use")
  .attr("href", "#square")
  .attr("y", 10)
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return d
  })
  .attr("stroke-width", 2)
  .attr("stroke", "yellow")
  .attr("fill", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```